# No lee el Scanner ubicado en el main desde un método

Tags: java

El objeto `Scanner` ubicado en `main` **(ya que será utilizado desde varios métodos)** no toma el dato del usuario. El `Scanner` no me funciona.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
jugarPartida();
valoracionPartida();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
}

public static void jugarPartida(){
System.out.print("Introduce numero: ");
numero = sc.nextInt();
/*Aquí sucede un juego*/
}

public static void valoracionPartida(){
System.out.print("Introduce numero(0-10): ");
valoracion = sc.nextInt();
/*Aquí agradecerá la valoración*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para usar la clase scanner de forma global, basta con iniciarla en la clase main, es decir, en la clase principal, no dentro del método main. También faltaba por declarar las variables número y valoración que en ese caso si iría dentro de sus métodos a menos que quieras usarlos en otros métodos, en ese caso iría también fuera del método main, en la clase principal. Quedaría así:

```java
package main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        jugarPartida();
        valoracionPartida();        
    }
        public static void jugarPartida(){      
        int numero;
        System.out.print("Introduce numero: ");
        numero = sc.nextInt();
        /*Aquí sucede un juego*/
        }

        public static void valoracionPartida(){
        int valoracion;
        System.out.print("Introduce numero(0-10): ");
        valoracion = sc.nextInt();
        /*Aquí agradecerá la valoración*/
        }
}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada compañero.

Answer (score 2):

> > No lee el Scanner ubicado en el main desde un método

Esto se debe porqué el identificador `sc` no está declarado en los métodos `jugarPartida` y `valoracionPartida`, por ende, dará un error de compilación, debido a que, el compilador lo tomará como que si nunca existió.

Una posible solución, es agregar un parámetro adicional (de tipo `Scanner`) en los métodos `jugarPartida` y `valoracionPartida`, de este modo, al momento de invocar estos métodos, podrás pasar la referencia del objeto al que apuntaba el puntero implícito `sc` (el del método `main`).

Quedaría de esta forma:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Le pasamos la referencia que tenga guardada el puntero sc
        jugarPartida(sc);
        valoracionPartida(sc);
    }

    public static void jugarPartida(Scanner sc)
    {
        int numero;
        System.out.print("Introduce numero: ");
        numero = sc.nextInt();
    }

    public static void valoracionPartida(Scanner sc)
    {
        int valoracion;
        System.out.print("Introduce numero(0-10): ");
        valoracion = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

También recalco que faltó declarar las variables `valoracion` y `numero`, de lo contrario, habrá error de compilación (porqué el identificador/nombre nunca será creado para el compilador).

Otra solución es declarar el identificador `sc` como global.

El código quedaría de esta manera:

```
public class Program
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        jugarPartida();
        valoracionPartida();
    }

    public static void jugarPartida()
    {
        int numero;
        System.out.print("Introduce numero: ");
        numero = sc.nextInt();
    }

    public static void valoracionPartida()
    {
        int valoracion;
        System.out.print("Introduce numero(0-10): ");
        valoracion = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Pero si te das cuenta, si compilamos desde la línea de comandos: `javac Program.java`, notaremos que nos dio un error de compilación:

`non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`

**¿Qué significa este error?**

Esto significa que los métodos `jugarPartida` y `valoracionPartida` necesitan la referencia del objeto (en este caso de tipo `Program`), sin embargo, la verdadera razón del error, es porqué nunca se creó ningún objeto de tipo `Program`, entonces, ¿como el método estático podría acceder al atributo `sc` si en realidad el objeto no existe? Pues la respuesta sería **NO**. No es posible y tampoco tiene sentido.

**¿Hay alguna solución sin la necesidad de agregar la palabra clave `static` a la variable `sc`?**

Pues si la hay. Una forma para evitar ese error, es agregando un parámetro adicional a los métodos `jugarPartida` y `valoracionPartida`, en la cual, ese parámetro será de tipo `Program` y tendríamos que instanciar la clase en el método `main` y mandar esa referencia del objeto al parámetro del método.

En código sería de esta forma:

```
public class Program
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        jugarPartida(p);
        valoracionPartida(p);
    }

    public static void jugarPartida(Program p)
    {
        int numero;
        System.out.print("Introduce numero: ");
        numero = p.sc.nextInt();
    }

    public static void valoracionPartida(Program p)
    {
        int valoracion;
        System.out.print("Introduce numero(0-10): ");
        valoracion = p.sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

De este modo, no dará error de compilación porqué el objeto fue creado y el puntero implícito `p` (de tipo `Program`) tendrá la referencia del objeto y de esta manera podremos acceder al atributo `sc` sin ningún problema.

Sin embargo, notamos que esta solución nos hace instanciar la clase cuando en realidad el objeto de tipo `Program` será creado una única vez, por lo tanto, es innecesario, porque no tendremos más objeto de tipo `Program`. Entonces, para no crear un objeto de por gusto, podríamos declarar la variable global `sc` como estática y ahí no necesitaríamos que los métodos tenga una referencia del objeto de tipo `Program`, porqué la variable `sc` estaría almacenado en una zona estática (en esta zona de memoria es donde se registran los datos estáticos que duran hasta que el programa finalice) y es válido poder acceder al contenido de la variable `sc` en un método estático, porqué la variable `sc` no estaría en un objeto.

Con los cambios hechos, llegamos a este código:

```
public class Program
{
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        jugarPartida();
        valoracionPartida();
    }

    public static void jugarPartida()
    {
        int numero;
        System.out.print("Introduce numero: ");
        numero = sc.nextInt();
    }

    public static void valoracionPartida()
    {
        int valoracion;
        System.out.print("Introduce numero(0-10): ");
        valoracion = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error está en que tu `Scanner` deberia estar dentro de `jugarPartida()` o bien como global y la variable `numero` no está instanciada:

```
static Scanner sc;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    jugarPartida();

}

public static void jugarPartida(){
    System.out.print("Introduce numero: ");

    int numero = sc.nextInt();
    /*Aquí sucede un juego*/
    System.out.print("Esto se introdujo: " + numero);
}
```

Comment: El mismo scanner se utilizará en varios métodos, por eso mi interés de que se ubique en el main. Gracias Israel-ICM

Comment: bueno modifique el codigo con el scanner como global

Answer (score 1):

Para que puedas usarlo en más de un método debes declararlo de forma global:

```
public class Miclase{
   static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);//justo después de la clase

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        jugarPartida();
        valoracionPartida();

    }

    public static void jugarPartida(){
        System.out.print("Introduce numero: ");
        numero = sc.nextInt();
        /*Aquí sucede un juego*/
    }

    public static void valoracionPartida(){
        System.out.print("Introduce numero(0-10): ");
        valoracion = sc.nextInt();
    /*Aquí agradecerá la valoración*/
    }


}
```

De esta manera podrás usarlo en todos los métodos que se encuentren dentro de tu clase

**EDIT:**

Se debe de declarar la variable `static`, ya que solo así podrá ser usada en los métodos `static`:

```
 static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: Devuelve un error a la variable sc: error: non-static variable sc cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Disculpa, he modificado mi respuesta, resulta que todas las variables utilizadas dentro de un método estático, también deben de ser estáticas

Comment: gracias Riaven!